# Can using INDIRECT Formulas in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use code in app script like that:

```
function plus(x,y) {
   return x+y
  }
```

and in sheet add this formula and work fine : `=plus(A1,A2)` give me number in cell A1 + number in cell A2.

Now I need to change INDIRECT formula to use in app script like code above, this is my formula : `=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""&A1&"!$B$3"),"")` Give me result from another sheet. and final add to sheet `=indirect(A1,B3)` . can you give me example or exactly code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this custom function:

```
function CUSTOMINDIRECT(x,y) {
  const val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(x+"!"+y).getValue();
  if (val == "#N/A" || val == "#NAME?" || val == "#ERROR!" || val == "#VALUE!" || val == "#DIV/0!")
    return "";
  else
    return val;
}
```

**Sample:**

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

If you prefer using quotes on the second argument like in the INDIRECT function, you need to add a line to the code:

```
function CUSTOMINDIRECT(x,y) {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(y).getValue();
  const val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(x+"!"+cell).getValue();
  if (val == "#N/A" || val == "#NAME?" || val == "#ERROR!" || val == "#VALUE!" || val == "#DIV/0!")
    return "";
  else
    return val;
}
```

Comment: this work but this method in not exactly I change `=CUSTOMINDIRECT(C3,D3)` TO `=CUSTOMINDIRECT(C3,"D3")` and fine

Comment: @Catlos M this way work but a lot of time not working not good brother I don't know why?

Comment: What is the error? You can check custom function executions in script.google.com -> ````MY Executions````

Comment: empty cell and if I remove if function give me #ERROR! I use formula `=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""&A1&"!$B$3"),"")` it's work always fine but your code some times work and some time not

Comment: The ````if```` statement is equivalent to the ````IFERROR```` function, it's going to replace #ERROR! with an empty cell

Comment: Yeh, but why every time cell empty and the data from another sheet is present. I have another formula `=CUSTOMINDIRECT(A4,"A1")` this is give me value from another sheet. `A4` is a name if sheet and `A1` is a value I want to import. can you change it to code like above

Comment: Updated answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You Don't do anything just add const cell .Give me this result `#ERROR!` Exception: Range not found (line 127)